# Как правильно применить replaceAll() к введенному массиву?

Tags: java

На вход подается:

> 2 --- 3

Хотелось бы получить:

> 2 - 3

Код:

```
String[] blocks = scanner.nextLine().split(" ").replaceAll("---", "-");
```

Comment: @And хотел бы заменить в массиве три минуса на один минус или два минуса на один плюс

Comment: String[] blocks = scanner.nextLine().replaceAll("---", "-");
не работает, пишет несовместимые типы

Comment: Почему не использовать метод `replace`? Метод `replaceAll` в качестве первого аргумента ждёт регулярное выражение. Вообще, задача плохо сформулирована.

Answer (score -1):

```
String strArray = scanner.nextLine().replaceAll("---", "-").
                replaceAll("--", "+").
                replaceAll("\\+++", "+").
                replaceAll("  ", " ").
                replaceAll("   ", " ");
        String[] blocks = strArray.split(" ");
```